# How to print every 5 characters in a sequence of 'X' characters?

Tags: python, printing, sequence

How do I print every 5 characters in a sequence of 'X' characters such as:

```
9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use slices

```
print("9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08"[::5])
```

Output:

```
>>> '9045e51f22550'
```

Comment: This is better than my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use the slice-notation:

```
>>> "9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08"[::5]

    '9045e51f22550'
```

In combination with print:

```
>>> for i in "9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08"[::5]:
...   print i
...
9
0
4
5
e
5
1
f
2
2
5
5
0
```

Answer (score 1):

the [range](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function can accept an increment:

```
x = "9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08" 

for i in range(0, len(x), 5):
    print(x[i])
```

Update: If you want the output as a series of characters, you can use a generator expression:

```
>>> x = "9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08" 
>>> y = "".join(x[i] for i in range(0, len(x), 5))
>>> y
'9045e51f22550'
```

Comment: This works great, although I should have specified I also want the output as a sequence of characters. Thanks.

Comment: Updated, but Yoann's / dorvak's answers are of course more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an iterator with range that goes by arbitrary increments by passing a third argument to it like this:

```
a = "1234567890"

for x in range(0, len(a), 5):
    print(a[x])
```

Dorvak and Yoann suggested slice notation. That is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

```
teststring = "9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08"    

for num, letter in enumerate(teststring, 1):
    if num % 5 == 0:
        print letter
```

Enumerate will count up from the starting index of 1 and we can use that index for printing letters cleanly divisible by 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
value = "9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08" 

for i in range(0,len(value),4):

      print i
```